# The strange case of the waxing and waning reputation

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I received +150 odd reputation points - someone had voted up all of my posts.

Today they were automatically removed.

> [image: Serial voting example]

Has anyone else been the victim of strange voting patterns?

Would whoever votes in this indiscriminate way, please refrain from doing so? It is better to receive points for posts of merit, rather than from some form of lottery.

Comment: from what I can tell this is the result of a serial upvoter     http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256224/voting-correction-and-faq-dont-add-up  and this is viewed as gaming the system, hence the rollback of reputation. While it is unfortunate please remember reputation is just a number; keep doing the positive things you have been doing and the number will increase. Asking them to stop is unlikely to have any effect (or even be seen/read).